# Basic Moving/Anim Script [Unity CSharp]

Tags: unity, c#, 2d, animation, sprites

So, I got this to do the anims for my sprite in Unity 2d...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Move : MonoBehaviour {
public float Speed = 2;
Animator anim;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Speed, 0);
    anim.SetFloat("HorizontalSpeed", Mathf.Abs(rigidbody2D.velocity.x));

if(transform.localScale.x > 0 && rigidbody2D.velocity.x  < 0)
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1, 1, 1); 

if(transform.localScale.x < 0 && rigidbody2D.velocity.x > 0)
    transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1); 

}
}
```

That works fine... then I add the script so he can move up and down. (the previous was moving left+right)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class UpMove : MonoBehaviour {
public float VerticalSpeed = 2;
Animator anim;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * VerticalSpeed, 0);
    anim.SetFloat("VerticalSpeed", Mathf.Abs(rigidbody2D.velocity.y));
}
}
```

Welll.. The second script doesn't do anything.
I've been working at this (rookie noobness) for around an hour now.. so pls pls pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're asking for the `y` property of the Vector2 you created, which is 0.  You set the input to `vec2.x`

Try:

```
void FixedUpdate () {
    rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(rigidbody2D.velocity.x, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * VerticalSpeed);
    anim.SetFloat("VerticalSpeed", Mathf.Abs(rigidbody2D.velocity.y));
}
```

Do same change for the `Horizontal` code too. Change `new Vector2(...,0)` to `new Vector2(...,rigidbody2D.velocity.y);`

Comment: Hey. thanks - Now the animation changes but the sprite does not move.. Let me double check some things.

Comment: Please explain.. I'm kind of a noob at this stuff.

Comment: You want to set Vertical Speed that relates to the `Y` axis in coordinate system. That's why I set `X` of `new Vector2` to `0` and set `Y` according to input.

Comment: Or in more simple words. In 2D coordinate system. Left and Right dependent on X-axis while Up and Down belongs to Y-axis

Comment: I see. What would I even change for the sprite to move? Because I make the vector2, getting what I'm pressing to go vertical, then it sets my float in the animation to the velocity of the y axis... I don't understand why that wouldn't do anything.. but Idk. The animation works, but the Y of the sprite does not change.

Comment: Try by changing `new Vector2(0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * VerticalSpeed);` to `new Vector2(rigidbody2D.velocity.x, Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * VerticalSpeed);` and for `Horizontal` change `rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Speed, 0);` to `rigidbody2D.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Speed, rigidbody2D.velocity.y);`

Comment: And double check (from Inspector) that your Rigidbody2D doesn't has mark check any of `X` of `Y` in `Constraints`'s `Freeze Position`

Comment: I just found this.. If I turn off the left and right (X axis) movement, and keep the up (Y axis) on, the up script works... but when they are both on, only the X axis script works. So basically, it works but only one at a time.

Comment: Change in `Horizontal` code too. As I mentioned in comment above

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I really appreciate it. lmao